# get live position of draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if anyone of you has a clue how to solve following problem:

I have a lots of divs

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

and they all are draggable with jquery ui

```
var $divs = $('#one, #two, #three')
$divs.draggable({   
     start: dragStart, cursor: 'move', stop: dragEnd        
      });
```

what I want to is that I get the current position of the dragged element in realtime so that if an event is triggered if the dragged div is for example:

```
if($('#two').position().left <= 500) { /*baadaboom*/ }
```

I drag the div at a point where

> left is 1000px

and immediately if its

> smaller than 500px

it should fire!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following

```
var $divs = $('#one, #two, #three')
$divs.draggable({
    start: dragStart, cursor: 'move', stop: dragEnd,
    drag: function () {
        var t = $(this), l = $(this).offset().left;
        t.text(l);

        if(l < 500){
           t.text('Badaboom');
        }
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/enNRE/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: very cool solution. im just wondering how this works, i thought this would only fire if the div at dragging point is under 500. how does it get the "live" position? thanks anyways!

Comment: `drag: function () {}` fires when the `element` is dragged, updating `var l` with the `.offset().left` position. [See here the events](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)

Comment: if you are changing the div's position programmatically, you could try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/enNRE/6/embedded/result/). Press on the `Hmm` button

Answer (score -1):

Take a global variable var position and set it when the div is clicked to drag. Then you can use this variable to comparision.